# fixed positioned left menu with jquery effects problems?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a left side button with fixed position, when clicked it slides to the right and also another div to its left slide to the right and show some options.

I managed to do the effect in Jquery and css. *However* there is one **bug**, **when I scroll down one page or more and press the button at that position, it goes back to top and do the effect!**

it just works fine at the top of the website!

Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".events, .messages").click(function() {
    $(".side-menu").toggleClass("sideMenu-expand");
    $(".side-buttons").toggleClass("sideButtons-expand");
});
```

here is my html:

```
 <div class="side-menu">    
    <div class="side-buttons">
        <ul>

        <li ><a class="events" href="#"></a></li>
        <li ><a class="messages" href="#"></a></li>

        </ul>        
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my Css:

```
.side-menu{
height:300px;
background:#fff;
width:150px;
position:fixed;
margin-left:-158px;
margin-top:100px;
border:7px solid #232323;
border-radius: 8px; 
-moz-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0px; /* vendor specific for mozilla */
-webkit-border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0px; /* vendor specific for webkit browsers */
float:left;
}
.sideMenu-expand{
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:-7px;

}
.side-buttons{
    width:40px;
    height:100px;
    margin-top:100px;
    background:url(images/side-button.png) no-repeat;
position:fixed;
margin-left:152px;
float:left;
z-index:100000;
}
 .side-buttons ul{
    list-style-type:none;
}
.side-buttons ul li a.events{
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:18px;
    margin-top:12px;
    margin-left:-1px;
    background:url(images/icons/events.png) no-repeat;
}
.side-buttons ul li a.events:hover{
    background:url(images/icons/events-ho.png) no-repeat;
}
.side-buttons ul li a.messages{
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:18px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    background:url(images/icons/messages.png) no-repeat;
    }
.side-buttons ul li a.messages:hover{
background:url(images/icons/messages-ho.png) no-repeat;
       }

.sideButtons-expand{
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:155px;
    z-index:100000;
}
```

my code basically add margin-left to side-menu and to the side-buttons when a button is clicked.

your help will be appreciated. 
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a "#" in you menu items' `href`, which is essentially a link to the top of the page.
Either get rid of the "#" in the `href`, or use `e.preventDefault()` in the click handler for the menu items.